# Oracle Coherence index not working with ContainsFilter query

Tags: indexing, filter, oracle-coherence

I've added an index to a cache. The index uses a custom extractor that extends AbstractExtractor and overrides only the extract method to return a List of Strings. Then I have a ContainsFilter which uses the same custom extractor that looks for the occurence of a single String in the List of Strings. It does not look like my index is being used based on the time it takes to execute my test. What am I doing wrong? Also, is there some debugging I can switch on to see which indices are used?

```
public class DependencyIdExtractor extends AbstractExtractor {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Object extract(Object oTarget) {
        if (oTarget == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (oTarget instanceof CacheValue) {
            CacheValue cacheValue = (CacheValue)oTarget;
            // returns a List of String objects
            return cacheValue.getDependencyIds();
        }
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Adding the index:

```
mCache = CacheFactory.getCache(pCacheName);
mCache.addIndex(new DependencyIdExtractor(), false, null);
```

Performing the ContainsFilter query:

```
public void invalidateByDependencyId(String pDependencyId) {
    ContainsFilter vContainsFilter = new ContainsFilter(new DependencyIdExtractor(), pDependencyId);
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Set setKeys = mCache.keySet(vContainsFilter);
    mCache.keySet().removeAll(setKeys);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding a hashCode and equals method implementation to the DependencyIdExtractor class. It is important that you use exactly the same value extractor when adding an index and creating your filter.

```
public class DependencyIdExtractor extends AbstractExtractor {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Object extract(Object oTarget) {
        if (oTarget == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (oTarget instanceof CacheValue) {
            CacheValue cacheValue = (CacheValue)oTarget;
            return cacheValue.getDependencyIds();
        }
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (obj instanceof DependencyIdExtractor) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

To debug Coherence indices/queries, you can generate an explain plan similar to database query explain plans.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/tutorials/tutorial-1841899.html

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void invalidateByDependencyId(String pDependencyId) {
        ContainsFilter vContainsFilter = new ContainsFilter(new DependencyIdExtractor(), pDependencyId);

        if (mLog.isTraceEnabled()) {
            QueryRecorder agent = new QueryRecorder(RecordType.EXPLAIN); 
            Object resultsExplain = mCache.aggregate(vContainsFilter, agent);

            mLog.trace("resultsExplain = \n" + resultsExplain + "\n");
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Set setKeys = mCache.keySet(vContainsFilter);
        mCache.keySet().removeAll(setKeys);
    }
```